# Minimum distance required to turn at maximum speed of an F-16

Tags: f-16, mid-air-collision

What would be the minimum distance required for an F-16 to turn either sideways or upwards in order to avoid a collision (assume an infinitely long wall both length and breadth wise).

Also would it be better for such planes to turn sideways or upwards? Which is faster and requires less distance.

Comment: Someone please help me with the tags, I don’t think that they are sufficient.

Comment: To clarify, are you asking about the diameter of a 180 degree course reversal?  (Because you only need to turn a few degrees to avoid a collision...)

Comment: @MichaelHall : I am assuming an infinitely long wall so turning a few degrees won’t help. Also, I want to know about the radius of a 90 degree course reversal, a 180 diameter would help too.

Comment: Ok, I read the wall part, but didn't really get it.  I can't calculate the answer, but rolling inverted and pulling will give the best radius because you aren't fighting gravity.  You get an extra one G from mother earth...

Comment: @MichaelHall : So, a downward turn around would be faster and shorter?

Comment: Subtracting the time it takes to snaproll 180, yes.  But only for the first 90 degrees of turn.  After that you are working against gravity and your turn radius will increase.  But by then you are parallel to the wall.

Comment: @MichaelHall : I didn’t think of the extra G that we would get, so I have half of the answer, the only thing that remains is the distance. Thank You.

Comment: @MichaelHall : Being parallel won’t be an issue as I only want to avoid the collision, and after that taking another small turn won’t matter, because maneuvering is the most important part as it takes a lot of time and distance which is difficult at high speeds. Also, with regards to the plane that bombed H & N, it would save most of it’s time by making the fastest maneuver possible.

Comment: A level turn will give a constant radius, and may be the best option for 180 deg.

Comment: @MichaelHall : Yeah, even that would do but now that I think of it, the downward turn seems more practical.

Comment: On the other hand, an upward turn (half-loop) will have gravity helping you slow down, which will decrease the turn radius assuming you're limited throughout by max permissible structural G load. You'd want to pull the power to idle too.

Comment: @pericynthion : Even that’s true but since I want to have maximum speed, a downward turn would help.

Comment: It'd probably be a good idea to clarify in the question that your scenario has the aircraft not only starting at maximum speed but maintaining maximum speed throughout the maneuver.

Comment: @pericynthion : Yup I will do it right away.

Comment: Is there any particular reason the aircraft needs to maintain top speed throughout the maneuver, or is that an arbitrary requirement? If it *is* an arbitrary requirement, that's totally fine, but it would be good to know whether it's arbitrary or there's a reason behind it.

Comment: @TerranSwett : As I mentioned in the question, I thought of this when I read about the planes that bombed H & N and I am trying to co-relate things, in order for those pilots in their planes(not F-16s) to take the fastest turn possible to come back alive. So we can say that it is arbitrary requirement as the most important thing is less amount of time and more distance to be covered which can be achieved either by maximum speed or by least possible distance to cover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this F-16 turn performance chart](http://www.f-16.net/forum/download/file.php?id=20016&sid=824253ac1f559159bddc21c86b1d69d8&mode=view), at the rated maximum airspeed of 800 knots, an F-16 can turn at about 10.5 degrees per second, so a 90° turn would take about 8.5 seconds. The turn radius would be 9,000 feet. Since you specified a 90° turn to avoid an infinite wall, the pilot would have to start their turn at or before 9,000 feet from the wall in order to avoid a collision.

However, this doesn't tell the whole story. The F-16 can't maintain speed in such a turn, and the reduced speed would in turn reduce the turning radius. If the plane, for whatever reason, absolutely *had* to maintain its maximum speed, then it would be limited to a turn rate of 3.5 degrees per second and a turning radius of 25,000 feet.

Comment: If the point of the exercise is to avoid the infinite wall, then bleeding airspeed would be immensely ***helpful*** since it reduces your turn radius... go idle, 90 degrees bank, and pull 9 G's; the speed will bleed off *rapidly* and the turn will be complete much sooner than 9,000'. Or idle & pull 9 G's straight up, bleeding speed in the vertical, adding power as necessary to complete the Immelman.

Comment: @RalphJ True, but since the OP was very specific about the "flying as fast as possible" part, I assumed they wanted top speed maintained throughout the turn. Unfortunately, I don't know of any published performance information for *any* plane that includes variable-speed turns, so you'd either have to simulate the turn mathematically (something that's beyond me), or else get a real F-16 and test it (also beyond me).

Comment: @HiddenWindshield : Your assumption was right(should have mentioned it, my fault sorry). Also, could you include the turning downward part so that that I can mark it as the answer.

Comment: @RalphJ : Would the pilot experience **9 G’s**!! of force ?!?!

Comment: @valay_17 Well, it's an F-16... you want max performance, you should expect 9 G's.

Comment: @RalphJ : Yeah , hehe silly me.

Comment: @HiddenWindshield  If the scenario is to avoid crashing into an obstacle, the idea of maneuvering but ***only*** in such a way that the speed can't decay (even if that requirement impedes the ability to avoid death by crashing), has left the realm of reality & entered into an academic, and not particularly interesting, exercise. If you're not allowed to pull max G because doing so would bleed airspeed & reduce the turn radius, then "maintain parameters" has become more important than survival, and it's hard to keep caring about such a hypothetical at that point.

Comment: @Valay_17 Unfortunately, no, I can't add the turning radius for a vertical turn. Such information isn't usually published, simply because publishing performance numbers for every single possible maneuver would be impossible. So figuring that out would involve some kind of simulation, as I said.

Comment: I'm with @Ralph J on this.  I enjoy entertaining hypothetical scenarios, but this question is a confusing mish-mash of WWII bombers, infinite walls, F-16 max speed, and F-16 best turn rate.  Most tactical aircraft have a best performance "bug out" defensive maneuver that the pilots are familiar with if the stuff hits the fan.  I imagine this would be vastly different for a fighter vs bomber, and I am only qualified to say what an EA-6B Prowler might do.  All else is speculation for what is becoming an increasingly "not particularly interesting exercise".

Comment: @RalphJ : I see your point and it is true, I removed the requirement to make the question a less of hypothetical one and more of a factual one.

Comment: @MichaelHall : It was quite confusing but I got the necessary information and I totally agree with Ralph J.